# is it possible to have different commands for different prefixes in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

Is it possible to have different commands for each prefix? For example, one command for `!` and another command for `?` For example, someone does `!foo`  the bot responds with `"foo"`, but another person does `?foo` the bot responds with `"bar"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a bot with two prefixes and create a `foo` command. Then check what prefix was used to invoke a command using `ctx.prefix`.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=("!", "?"))


@bot.command()
async def foo(ctx):
    await ctx.send("foo" if ctx.prefix == "!" else "bar")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

Or you can do it manually using `on_message` event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == "!foo":
        await message.channel.send("foo")
    elif message.content.lower() == "?foo":
        await message.channel.send("bar")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```